# make the same highlight as in the search browser through the method replace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, replace, str-replace

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-leftpad-ck6k9s?file=/src/App.tsx

Must be done through the method replace,highlighting letters or words while maintaining their case, and the search string can be any

Now the selection works in such a way that it changes the original letters, for example, if you make a selection by letter 'P' then all letters 'P' become capital letters. It is necessary to make the letters remain as they were originally, but the highlighting works in case-independent. Where the big letter remained large where the small remained small.

in fact, I am doing an analogue of highlighting in the browser through controll f

[image: correct result]

[image: wrong result]

DataHighlighting.tsx

```
interface Props {
  data: string;
  searchString: string;
}

const DataHighlighting = ({ data, searchString }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const regex = new RegExp(searchString, "gi");

  return (
    <span
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: data.replace(
          regex,
          `<span style="background: #ff0">${searchString}</span>`
        )
      }}
    ></span>
  );
};

export default DataHighlighting;
```

App.tsx

```
import "./styles.css";
import DataHighlighting from "./DataHighlighting";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Programming learning programming for Programming up
      <div />
      <DataHighlighting
        data={"Programming learning programming for Programming up"}
        searchString={"P"}
      />
      <div />
      <DataHighlighting
        data={"Programming learning programming for Programming up"}
        searchString={"programming"}
      />
      <div />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/regex-case-vr2jxk?file=/src/DataHighlighting.tsx

And here is the summary:

```
data.replace(
          regex,
          (match) => `<span style="background: #ff0">${match}</span>`
        )
```

Use the callback to get what you are replacing; instead of replacing it with your argument, use that callback value, which is case-sensitive.

Complete code, for your convenience:

```
interface Props {
  data: string;
  searchString: string;
}

const DataHighlighting = ({ data, searchString }: Props): JSX.Element => {
  const regex = new RegExp(searchString, "ig");

  return (
    <span
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: data.replace(
          regex,
          (match) => `<span style="background: #ff0">${match}</span>`
        )
      }}
    ></span>
  );
};

export default DataHighlighting;
```

And:

```
import "./styles.css";
import DataHighlighting from "./DataHighlighting";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Programming learning programming for Programming up
      <div />
      <DataHighlighting
        data={"Programming learning programming for Programming up"}
        searchString={"P"}
      />
      <div />
      <DataHighlighting
        data={"Programming learning programming for Programming up"}
        searchString={"programming"}
      />
      <div />
    </div>
  );
}
```